# Ran out of registers during register allocation

Tags: xcode4.5, neon, clang-static-analyzer

I just updated to Xcode 4.5.1.  Now when I 'Analyze' my code, I get this error.  Please note that it compiles and runs just fine. Any idea why this is?

Updated 10/25
Actually, my code compiles and runs fine in Release configuration. However, in the Debug configuration, I get the "Ran out of registers..." error as I would when I 'Analyzed' with the clang-static-analyzer. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please file a bug report if you haven't already  (bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: submitted.  Bug ID# 14300314